# Suitable PHP Framework for user profile management website

Tags: php, frameworks, content-management-system

I am designing an online portal website which would basically have the following functionality:

1. New visitor registers with the site as a member
2. If she is a paid member, then she should be given the privileges to login as make changes to her profile. Imagine a Facebook profile, every user logs in and is capable of changing their information, adding new photos, etc.
3. If she is a free member, then it should only give a basic level profile without much admin functionality.
4. If a guest user registers with the site, then they should be given the opportunity to contact the free and paid members of the site through a messaging system 
   All free and paid members need to get their profile approved by the site admin and an email verification

I am familiar with Joomla, WordPress, Prestashop, Magento and Yii, but I still do not have an idea of how to have a super admin for the complete website and an individual admin for each user account.

Any ideas on how this could be accomplished?

Comment: Defining groups and permissions to each group would help. each user is part of a group and each group can do X things. read more about ACL here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list or find a plugin to your current framework that does it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a custom job, there will be no one framework to accomplish your goals.

You should understand that frameworks are only a base layer of code that has been tested and proven secure. It's then up to you to use the framework's APIs properly to build an efficient web application.

You're best bet would be to pick one of the mainstream php frameworks:

- [Symfony](http://symfony.com/)
- [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/)
- [CodeIgnitor](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter)
- [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/)
- [FuelPHP](http://fuelphp.com/)

Research each of the frameworks (this is not exhaustive) and choose the one that matches your needs and skill level.

Comment: I went through those frameworks and several others as well. However I got a plan in my mind yesterday to do this project using Prestashop. As I only need to basically find a way to 1. Display items based on suppliers in product and search results pages 2. Create a seperate admin interface for every single supplier and 3. Find a way to create membership levels for every supplier (this I still need to find out)
I havent decided on this though, but if it works out the way I want then I would continue with it

Comment: Otherwise I shall use Zend or FuelPHP